# Limit the maximum number of subscribers to which is delivered a message in a Topic in ActiveMq

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, jms-topic

Let's say there is an ActiveMq instance and there are 100 client that listen to a Topic.
When a new message is published in the Topic, is it possible to limit the number of subscribers that receive it (example only 10)?

If now are other Messaging Component able to do that or there is a work-around / consolidtated best practice?

Answer (score 0):

It's not configureable out of the box, but you can create a plugin to do such a thing pretty simple.

A plugin that intercepts `addConsumer` and throws some `SecurityException` if there are too many subscribers already. It can be made configureable from `activemq.xml` config as well.

Please be aware that this is a quick and dirty example, you probably need to enhance it.

**MaxSubscribersPlugin.java**

```
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerPluginSupport;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.ConnectionContext;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Destination;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.region.Subscription;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQDestination;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ConsumerInfo;

import java.util.Map;

public class MaxSubscribersPlugin extends BrokerPluginSupport{

    private int maxSubscribers = 1000;

    @Override
    public Subscription addConsumer(ConnectionContext ctx, ConsumerInfo info) throws Exception {
        ActiveMQDestination dest = info.getDestination();
        if ( dest.isTopic()  && !dest.getQualifiedName().contains("Advisory")) { // TODO better way to filter out Advisories
            Map<ActiveMQDestination, Destination> destinations =  ctx.getBroker().getBrokerService()
                                                                    .getAdminView().getBroker().getDestinationMap();
            Destination activeTopic = destinations.get(info.getDestination());
            if( activeTopic != null && activeTopic.getConsumers().size() >= getMaxSubscribers() ) {

                throw new SecurityException("Too many active subscribers on topic "
                        + info.getDestination().getPhysicalName()
                        + ". Max is " + getMaxSubscribers());
            }
        }

        return super.addConsumer(ctx, info);
    }

    public int getMaxSubscribers() {
        return maxSubscribers;
    }

    public void setMaxSubscribers(int maxSubscribers) {
        this.maxSubscribers = maxSubscribers;
    }

}
```

Pack it up in a .jar and put it in ActiveMQ's lib-folder. Then you can configure it.

```
    <plugins>
          <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" id="throttler"
              class="my.package.MaxSubscribersPlugin">
            <property name="maxSubscribers" value="10"/>
        </bean>
    </plugins>
```

Then, if too many consumers connect - they will get an exception: `javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: Too many active subscribers on topic topicX. Max is 10`

There will be a log entry in the ActiveMQ log as well:

`WARN | Security Error occurred on connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52335, Too many active subscribers on topic topicX. Max is 10`